# Min Cost Flow Optimized for a Complete Bipartite Matching in Euclidean Space

Tags: algorithm, matching, euclidean-distance, bipartite, network-flow

The gist is... we have two sets of points *A* and *B*. Set *A* and *B* have the same number of points *n*.

**Formal Problem:**

Construct a minimum cost complete bipartite matching between points in *A* and *B*. The cost of a matching *(a, b)* is the *distance(a, b)*. Does there exist an algorithm faster than *O(n^3)*?

**Notes:**

- Every point *a* in *A* and point *b* in *B* is in a matching *(a, b)*.
- Every point *a* in *A* or *B* is in exactly one matching.
- *sum(* *distance(a, b)* for every *(a, b)* matching *)* is minimized.

**Example:**

- Point a (0,0)
- Point b (2,0)
- Point c (0,1)
- Point d (-2,2)
- Set Z {a, d}
- Set Y {b, c}

**Solution:**

Matching 1: (a, b) (d, c)

*sum*(*distance*(a, b), *distance*(d, c)) = 2 + sqrt(5) ~ 4.23

Matching 2: (a, c) (d, b)

*sum*(*distance*(a, c), *distance*(d, b)) = 1 + sqrt(20) ~ 5.47

Matching 1 (a, b) (d, c) is the min cost complete bipartite matching!

Comment: Have you considered casting this as a [maximum flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) problem?

Comment: Yup. Used an algorithm for min cost max flow to solve this in _O(n^3)_ time. The network flow had _n^2_ edges and _n_ vertices. Looking for a faster algorithm! How can I optimize the min cost max flow knowing prior that every vertex is in the euclidean space and every edge is a euclidean distance?

Comment: I have no useful input or experience to provide but this seems a rather gnarly problem to solve. Are you certain that you cannot get away with an approximation in your particular application? I imagine that a greedy matching can't be too far for graphs of a size where O(N^3) becomes a burden. I apologize if this is a purely theoretical exercise but you did posted here rather than at https://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @doynax For my application, an approximation works if it's bounded. I'd need to know how good the approximation is. The accepted answer lists some gnarly algorithms for this.

Comment: Are you planning to implement this?  Where do the points come from, or how are they distributed?

Comment: @tmyklebu Yes. I have implemented this with [Google or-tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/flow/mincostflow) The two sets being compared are sets of color vectors. Each vector is a color in the LAB space. The euclidean distance in the LAB color space is defined as the color difference between two vectors. A set of colors is defined as a color palette. The euclidean bipartite minimum cost is defined as the difference between the two color palettes.

Comment: How big are the sets?

Comment: @tmyklebu So for the current application, its sets of 3 to 10 (simple color palette) but I need to do 100,000 comparisons with different sets of 3 to 10. Looking at another application of the algorithm where its set of 100,000 (every pixel in an image).

Comment: OK.  For the smaller instances, I don't think the geometry will help you.  For sets of 100000, perhaps try building a sparse graph where each point is connected to its 10 (or so) nearest neighbours and running a good min-cost matching code.  Another heuristic, suggested by that Agarwal-Varadarajan paper, is to snap your input points to a relatively coarse grid and find the matching there.  A trick:  The union of two matchings is a collection of even cycles; you're allowed to pick the cheaper half of each even cycle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. If the distances between vertices are taken as the weights of the edges between them, then this is a weighted bipartite graph. The task of finding the maximum/minimum weight matching is known as the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).

The problem can be solved in *O(|V|(|E|+|V| log |V|)* time using methods developed in [Fredman and Tarjan (1987)](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall03/cs528/handouts/fibonacci%20heaps.pdf).

There are further improvements possible in Euclidean spaces. As discussed [here](https://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall08/cps234/projects/sayan_proj.pdf). Notably, [Vaidya (1988)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.120.1353&rep=rep1&type=pdf) presents a *O(n² log n)* algorithm for the L1, L2, and L∞ metrics which improves to *O(n² (log n)³)* for the L1 and L∞ metrics. [Agarwal, Efrat, and Sharir (2006, Section 7)](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Alon_Efrat/publication/2814042_Vertical_Decomposition_of_Shallow_Levels_in_3-Dimensional_Arrangements_and_Its_Applications/links/0c9605227fe03635a8000000.pdf) improve on this, giving an algorithm that runs in *O(n^(2+ε))* time.

You can do even better if you sacrifice exactness. [Agarwal and Varadarajan (2004)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.72.3542&rep=rep1&type=pdf) present a probabilistic algorithm which, given a value *0<ε<1*, finds in *O(n^(1+ε))* time a matching with expected cost within a multiplicative *O(log(1/ε))* of the optimal.

Do your points happen to lie on the edges of a convex polygon? Then [Marcotte and Suri (1991)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0220026) will be of interest: they present an exact *O(n log n)* algorithm for that. If the polygon is non-convex, but still simple, then you could use their *O(n² log n)* algorithm in the same paper.

Comment: Thank you! Marked your answer as correct. Do you know if these algorithms are used in practice?

Comment: @MichaelPetrochuk: Alas, I'm afraid I don't know that.